# Python: Declare as integer and character

Tags: python, declare

```
# declare score as integer
score = int

# declare rating as character
rating = chr

# write "Enter score: "
# input score
score = input("Enter score: ")

# if score == 10 Then
#   set rating = "A"
# endif
if score == 10:
    rating = "A"

print(rating)
```

When I execute this code and enter "10" I get, built-in function chr, in the shell. I want it to print A, or another character depending on the score. For example if the input score was 8 or 9 it would have to read B. But, I'm trying to get past the first step first. I am new to programming, and if I can get pointed in the right direction that would help a lot.

Comment: You don’t really declare variables in Python\*; you just assign to them, which creates them if necessary. (\* except for with type annotations, and those still aren’t declarations.)

Comment: It looks like you need to either read a tutorial or stop skipping large sections of the one you're using.

Comment: The reason your `score == 10` check isn’t working is that `input()` returns a string, so you’ll have `"10" == 10`, which is False. Convert the input to an `int` using `int(input("Enter score: "))`.

Comment: I recommend you take a class in Python.  For now go through this lesson on variables and types: https://www.learnpython.org/en/Variables_and_Types .

Answer (score 3):

```
# declare score as integer
score = int

# declare rating as character
rating = chr
```

Above two statement, assigns the function `int`, `chr`, not declaring the variable with the default value. (BTW, `chr` is not a type, but a function that convert the code-point value to character)

Do this instead:

```
score = 0    # or   int()
rating = ''  # or   'C'   # if you want C to be default rating
```

**NOTE** `score` is not need to be initialized, because it's assigned by `score = input("Enter score: ")`

Comment: Those variables don't even need to be initialized.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, Thank you the comment. `score` is not needed to be initialized, but `rating` should be initialized, because it is assigned conditionally.

Comment: Do you honestly not think there'll be an `else: rating = 'F'` there once they've figured out basic Python syntax (which should be considered basic research and off-topic for SO)?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, No, I don't. I think, it depend on programming style. Some uses `if .. else ..`, some prefer initialize default value beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

In python, you can't do static typing (i.e. you can't fix a variable to a type). Python is dynamic typing.

What you need is to force a type to the input variable.

```
# declare score as integer
score = '0' # the default score

# declare rating as character
rating = 'D' # default rating

# write "Enter score: "
# input score
score = input("Enter score: ")

# here, we are going to force convert score to integer
try:
    score = int (score)
except:
    print ('score is not convertable to integer')

# if score == 10 Then
#   set rating = "A"
# endif
if score == 10:
    rating = "A"

print(rating)
```